# Validate Session Id, session variables secure?

Tags: php, security, session

I've made a website which has private discussion forums.

I'm relatively new to PHP, and much of my website relies on the Session named defined by the username which was inputted during login.

The code for this is...

```
$_SESSION["name"] = $name; // name is what the user put in as username
```

However, someone has managed to bypass this. They wrote this in a private forum which is unlikely that they would know the password to:

> *"Bro you need to read up on some cool php shiz bro. Bro I can like totally log in to any forum without the password bro."
>
> "But like totally bro your php session ID's aren't validated bro."*

What does he mean by validate the session id? I assume he's doing something to change his session name, but I don't really know. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: This could be related to session hijacking. Check out https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_hijacking_attack and Google "session hijacking" to see more results. Also, it could depend what other code you're using, if it isn't secured enough. If you're using an unsafe method in a database login method, then that could also be contributing. The question is unclear though and possibly too broad.

Comment: "much of my website relies on the Session named defined by the username" - this sounds troublesome. What do you do exactly?

Comment: @MarekPuchalski it determines which forums someone is a part of. When someone tries entering one, it checks if the forums members includes the session name

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've heard of Session hijacking, but I don't know how he would get any admin's session.